# SED script called from BASH: How can I shorten variable path in output?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am wrinting a sed invocation using a shell variable. The variable contains a path name with file name:

```
sed "file name is '$variable'"
...
variable=/path/path/file.txt
```

The problem is that I don't need the `/path/path/` part. I need just `file.txt` part in output.
Also my path is dynamic so I am guessing that I need to search (somehow) in a string for a first slash from the ending. How do I do that?

Comment: While the answers are spot-on with regards to truncating your `$variable`, are you sure about the `sed` line? That looks *pretty* confused to me, as those certainly aren't [`sed`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) instructions -- more like an `echo` statement, really...

Comment: @DevSolar Yep,I am sure. It's just an example .Real line is much more complicated , so I dont know if I answered your question :))

Comment: `sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: 'f'`. That's an `echo` line, not a `sed` line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the shell's variable substitution feature to remove parts matching a glob pattern:

```
$ variable=/path/path/file.txt
$ echo ${variable##*/}               # Remove longest left part matching "*/"
file.txt
```

From the bash manual:

> ```
> ${parameter#word}
> ${parameter##word}
>    The word is expanded to produce a pattern just as in pathname expansion.  If
>    the pattern matches the beginning of the value of parameter, then the result
>    of the expansion is the expanded value of parameter with the shortest match-
>    ing  pattern  (the  ‘‘#’’  case) or the longest matching pattern (the ‘‘##’’
>    case) deleted.  If parameter is @ or *, the  pattern  removal  operation  is
>    applied  to  each  positional  parameter  in  turn, and the expansion is the
>    resultant list.  If parameter is an array variable subscripted with @ or  *,
>    the  pattern  removal  operation  is  applied to each member of the array in
>    turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.
>
> ${parameter%word}
> ${parameter%%word}
>    The word is expanded to produce a pattern just as in pathname expansion.  If
>    the  pattern  matches a trailing portion of the expanded value of parameter,
>    then the result of the expansion is the expanded value of parameter with the
>    shortest  matching  pattern (the ‘‘%’’ case) or the longest matching pattern
>    (the ‘‘%%’’ case) deleted.  If parameter is @  or  *,  the  pattern  removal
>    operation is applied to each positional parameter in turn, and the expansion
>    is the resultant list.  If parameter is an array variable subscripted with @
>    or  *,  the pattern removal operation is applied to each member of the array
>    in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.
> ```

Comment: What do you mean? This is shell syntax and you usually call sed from the shell with some arguments like the sed script. So something like `sed -e "s,somestring,${variable##*/},"` will work if variable is a shell variable. A better answer can only be given if you show us the actual complete sed invocation.

Comment: I mean can use this sed "sometstring${variable##*/}"? I am using this in script. Would write actual but it is confidential info so I cant :/

Comment: Yes, you can use it like shown. This means you need the double quotes for the sed argument (single quotes will keep the shell from substituting the variable). It will not work if the sed script is in a file and called with `sed -f sed-script`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `basename` to do that:

```
basename /tmp/a.jpg
a.jpg
```

Comment: Ugh. A fork/exec for such a simple task? :-) But I grant you that basename handles the case of `/` slightly better.

Comment: @Jens I guess the author of `basename` thought it was worth a fork & exec... :-)